# How to reliably perform code before device shuts down?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I want to store some data on sharedPreferences when the phone shuts down.
I have a BroadcastReceiver for the ShutDown action. The problem is that it works sometimes and other times it doesn't.
The intent does not reach the BroadcastReceiver sometimes and others does.
Is there another way of detecting this?

Thanks

Comment: There is no guarantee that Android will fork a process for you, let alone give you time to perform I/O, during the shutdown sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a Service with **START_STICKY**:
Create a service and override the onTaskRemoved() method, which is called when the user removes a task from the recent tasks list. This could also indicate that the app is about to be closed.

```
public class ShutdownService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    // Save data to SharedPreferences when the app is removed from recent tasks
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("YourPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("key", "value");
    editor.apply();
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

Comment: Won't that also happen if the app throws a fatal exception?